# How to tell if I need to replace the transmission?

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission

Subaru Forester 2011, 4AT Transmission

I was planning a trip last month and noticed my car occasionally made a shake when accelerating from a stop. I sent the car to the dealer for an inspection, and they told me

1. The transmission needs to be replaced. The mech said the gears between 1 and 2, and 2 and 3 have problems
2. The front rotors are warped.

They said they only had new transmission and it would cost $5000, which is too much for a 10-year car. So I left my car in the parking lot and got another car for the trip.

Now I am back from the trip and try to find a cheaper alternative for the broken transmission. I first went to another mech to get the rotor/brake pads replaced. On my way back home, I noticed that all the problems seemed to disappear, and there was no more shaking when accelerating in the past two days.

I start to suspect if the dealer made a mistake in saying my transmission is broken? Should I replace the transmission now or just wait until it totally stops working?

Comment: I'd at least wait until your symptoms recur.  If they don't then you know the dealer was wrong.  If they do, I'd look at an independent shop who can install a rebuilt or a used transmission.   Putting a $5000 part in a 10 year old car likely makes no sense.

Comment: How many miles on it? Has the transmission fluid been ever changed? Note: there are **no** lifetime fluids, unless it is the lifetime of the tranny, which would end when the tranny breaks because the fluids were never changed.

Comment: @Jpe61, it has 101000 miles now. I changed the transmission fluid on 95000 miles last year. Before that, I changed the fluid 7 years ago when it has 40000 miles.

Comment: @jwh20 One thing I am not sure of is: How credible are the dealers? I was assuming dealers will charge you more but at least they make the right decisions because they have experienced mechanics. So when they said the transmission is problematic I tend to believe that. Maybe I am too naive?

Comment: In my experience dealers are not all that credible and their mechanics are more often than not just parts changers.  They change parts until the problem goes away and then charge you for everything.

Comment: I concur with @jwh20, have plenty on experience to back that up...